# Problem: Swish-e escapes the / in links to a subdirectory?

Tags: perl, search-engine, swish, search-engine-api

I'm running swish-e on a subdirectory htm/. On any search results page, the urls have the directory separator escaped, giving unusable links like htm%2Fpage.htm.

How do I get swish-e or search.cgi to not escape the urls in the results? I'm using the standard search.tt in search.cgi that came with the distribution, and my swish.config file says:

```
IndexOnly .htm .html
DefaultContents HTML*
StoreDescription HTML* <body>
MetaNames swishtitle swishdocpath
IndexDir htm
```

I run this in the parent directory:
    swish-e -c swish.config

Other than the unusable urls, the indexing and search.cgi work fine.